# Regular Expression in Javascript to parse input onKeyDown

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a onKeyDown and a regular expression to parse keyboard input.  I need it to all A-Z, backspace, and question mark.  The problem comes with the ?, I cannot get it to be accepted.  I have tried
    **/[A-Z\x08?]/**
    **/[A-Z\x08\?]/**
    **/[A-Z\x08\\?]/**
    **/[A-Z\x08\x3F]/**

None of which allow the ? to be accepted.

```
function kd(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /[A-Z\x08]/;
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent printing char in textbox when the reg matches, you should use keypress. And the reg is: `/^[a-zA-Z\x08\?]$/`. This works for me.

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\x08\?]$/;
// OR this one if you want uppercase letters:
var regex = /^[A-Z\x08\?]$/;
$("#regtest").keypress(function(event) {
    var _event = event || window.event;
    var key = _event.keyCode || _event.which;
    alert(key);
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    alert(key);
    if(regex.test(key)) {
        _event.returnValue = false;
        if (_event.preventDefault)
            _event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: better to match what you want matched rather than what you do not as the set is smaller with this regex you can enter a comma.

Answer (score 3):

The question mark should go inside the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/[A-Z\x08?]/
```

Another problem is that you should be using `onkeypress` to determine which character was typed. The `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` events only tell you which keys were pressed and released, but they don't say what characters these correspond to. On different keyboards you have to press different keys to generate the same character.

For example on my keyboard I have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> to get a `?`. On a US keyboard you typically have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> to get `?`. Because of this difference in keyboard layouts it is unreliable to use the onkeyup and onkeydown events to detect `?`.

Comment: Sorry that was me doing a bad paste.  I did have them in the class.  This expression above does not work for me.

Comment: Ok I will move it to the other event.  I was under the impression that the Sting.fromCharCode converted it from the keys pressed to the character those presses represent that I could parse against.